# Can't find drivers for ASUS P5G41T-M LX on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, raid, sata

I'm trying to install Windows 7, but stuck on window with message that I need a mass storage driver. But I can't find it at all. Here is my params:

> ASUS P5G41T-M LX Motherboard
>
> Intel(R) G41 ICH7 (Socket 775)
>
> RAID Controller SATA
>
> system: Windows 7 64bit.
>
> HARD DISK
>   Western Digital
>   Mass Storage WD1600AVJB-63SZA0
>
> Sil 0608 ATA/133 Medley RAID Controller BIOS Version 3.2.20

Seems I need a drivers on Controller:

`Sil0680ACLU144`

But I don't see on official [Silicon Image](http://www.siliconimage.com/) page them.

**SOLVED**

At Least I found the right drivers from here: [Sil 0860 ATA/133 Medley RAID Controller Drivers](http://devid.info/ru/27081/Silicon+Image+SiI+0680+Ultra-133+Medley+ATA+Raid+Controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download a RAID controller driver for your Ail 0608 ATA/133 controller from [here](http://silicon-image-sii-0680-ultra-133-medley-ata-raid-c.soft32.com/), assuming that you've connected your IDE harddrive to the controller.

It looks like your motherboard also has an IDE port on it directly; You should be able to use that instead of the RAID controller, and then you don't have to deal with drivers to install Windows.

Comment: seems I'm not able to download a drivers from there, or they're not exists there. I'll check my ports later, thanks.

Comment: Hi again, can you reupload somewhere the drivers for RAID Controller Driver from [here](http://silicon-image-sii-0680-ultra-133-medley-ata-raid-c.soft32.com/), caz my downloads not starting and mirrors not works.